# Trigger "unsaved changes" dialog for custom post meta changes

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, save-post

I'm using a custom post type with custom meta fields, but autosave and the "unsaved changes" dialog don't seem to be triggered for these custom meta fields. Autosave isn't as important to me as the unsaved changes dialog - is there a way to trigger it?

```
function add_meta_boxes() {
    add_meta_box('places_location', __('Location'), array(&$this, 'location_box'), 'place', 'normal', 'high');
}

function location_box($post) {
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'places_location_nonce');

    $lat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'places_lat', true);
    $lng = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'places_lng', true);

    ?>
    <p>
        <label>
            Latitude:
            <input name="places_lat" value="<?php echo esc_attr($lat); ?>" />
        </label>
        <label>
            Longitude:
            <input name="places_lng" value="<?php echo esc_attr($lng); ?>" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

function save_place($id) {
    // skip unverified location nonces
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['places_location_nonce'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) return;

    // skip autosave calls
    // commenting this out still doesn't trigger saving these fields on autosave
    //if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    // update our custom post meta
    update_post_meta($id, 'places_lat', (float)$_POST['places_lat']);
    update_post_meta($id, 'places_lng', (float)$_POST['places_lng']);
}
```

Comment: show us you metabox code

Comment: Didn't think it was all that necessary as the code is incredibly straightforward, but I added it anyway. Saving drafts and updating published posts works just fine, but changes to the custom fields does not trigger an "unsaved changes" dialog nor an autosave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code indeed [only looks at the TinyMCE editor](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/js/autosave.dev.js#L30) or the title and content field if the editor is hidden:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    var mce = typeof(tinyMCE) != 'undefined' ? tinyMCE.activeEditor : false, title, content;

    if ( mce && !mce.isHidden() ) {
        if ( mce.isDirty() )
            return autosaveL10n.saveAlert;
    } else {
        title = $('#post #title').val(), content = $('#post #content').val();
        if ( ( title || content ) && title + content != autosaveLast )
            return autosaveL10n.saveAlert;
    }
};
```

You could replace that [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) handler with your own (be sure to include the existing functionality of course). Or play with the `isDirty()` state of the TinyMCE editor and that `autosaveLast` value?

Comment: Any ideas why autosave isn't updating my custom post meta?

Comment: @Kevin: If you read the `autosave` function in that Javascript file, you will notice that it never looks at the meta fields. So you will also have to duplicate that function and add meta field data yourself. This is the reason why all those `save_post` handlers for metadata return early if `DOING_AUTOSAVE` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using [this excellent jQuery plugin](https://github.com/codedance/jquery.AreYouSure) that checks the dirty state of a form. It contains methods to checks added/removed/modified fields via javascript. It totally kicks ass!

I did not handled the "AUTOSAVE" (yet). 
I hope someone finds this useful.